# When HTTPConnection is performed and what is its status

Tags: java, http, outputstream, httpconnection

I have below code which generate OutputStream from `HttpURLConnection` 
 When connection is actually performed and how can I check its status?

```
  HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
  httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
  httpCon.addRequestProperty("X-Auth-Token", getAuthToken());
  httpCon.setDoInput(true);
  httpCon.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
  httpCon.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
  httpCon.setRequestProperty("Transfer-Encoding","chunked");
  httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
  httpCon.setChunkedStreamingMode(STREAMING_CHUNK);
  mOutputStream  = httpCon.getOutputStream();
```

Answer (score 3):

The underlying TCP connection is created (or allocated from a connection pool) when you get one of the streams or the response code, or call `connect()`. The `HttpURLConnection` object itself isn't a TCP connection.

Comment: So the connection is actually opened when i call getoutputstream?And how I check if this connection was successfully created.Could you please update you answer with some example.Thanks

Comment: So the connection is actually opened, as I already said, 'when you get one of the streams or the response code, or call `connect()`'. If the connection wasn't successfully created you get an `IOException`. I don't understand what it is that you want an example of, or why you think you need it.

Comment: I think what's missing here is a reference to [`HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29). Its result should be in the interval [200, 300[ for a successful operation in any case. But that really depends on the quality of the endpoint.